# Use Pause and backbutton event in PhoneGap 1.9

Tags: javascript, android, events, cordova

i have a problem with some Events in PhoneGap. When i try to register an event-listener to the pause and backbutton event for an phonegap-app (build on PhoneGap-Build) the events aren't recognized.

My code looks like the following:

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    console.log("Back");
}

function onMenuKeyDown() {
    console.log("Menu");
}

function pause() {
    console.log("Menu");
}

function ready(){
    console.log("ready");
    document.addEventListener("pause", pause, false);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready, false);
```

If i run this app on a HTC Wildfire i can see in the logs, that the function ready is reached (the output is done). But if i hit the Back or search button or exit the app, then no other function is called.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

---

The rest of my code looks like the following (I just wrote a small example to be sure that there are no errors in my code...)

main.js:

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    console.log("Back");
    alert("Back");
}

function onMenuKeyDown() {
    console.log("Menu");
    alert("Menu");
}

function onMenuSearch() {
    console.log("onMenuSearch");
    alert("onMenuSearch");
}

function pause() {
    console.log("Menu");
    alert("Pause");
}

function onResume(){
    console.log("Resume");
    alert("Resume");
}

function ready(){
    alert("Ready");
    console.log("ready");
    document.addEventListener("pause", pause, false);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("searchbutton", onMenuSearch, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume,false);
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready, false);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As I already said, I am using PhonegapBuild to build the application over several platforms, therfore i do not have the cordova script integrated in my application.

Thanks...

Comment: What does the rest of your html look like as this seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmm ... might be blind: but how is this different from the code already shown in the question? And how does it answer it? Please clarify